# How do I call a JavaScript method based on a variable value?

Tags: javascript

I have method `a()`, method `b()`, and method `c()`. I will get a response message from server, which contains `a` or `b` or `c` and so on.
If the response message is `a`, then I need to call method `a()`.
If the response message is `b`, then I need to call method `b()`
And so on...

I don't want to write any if else conditions or switch case to identify the method.

I don't want to do this:

```
if(res == 'a')
   a();
else if(res == 'b')
   b();
```

Instead of that I need something like reflections in Java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have defined the function in Global/window Scope then you can directly use `res` variable

```
window[res]();
```

Otherwise define the function in object and then use it

```
var obj = {
    a : function(){},
    b : function(){}
}   
obj[res]();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Working fine.

Answer (score 6):

You could use an object and store the function inside, like

```
var functions = {
    a: function () {},
    b: function () {},
    c: function () {}
    default: function () {} // fall back
}
```

Usage:

```
functions[res]();
```

Or with default

```
(functions[res] || functions.default)();
```

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose you can define a class that allows you to define and call methods, and determine the calling context:

```
var MethodsWorker = function () {
    this._context = window;
    this._methods = {};
}

MethodsWorker.prototype.setContext = function (context) {
    this._context = context;
}

MethodsWorker.prototype.defineMethod = function (name, method) {
    this._methods[name] = method;
};

MethodsWorker.prototype.invoke = function (methodName, args) {
    var method = this._methods[methodName];
    if (!method) { throw {}; }
    return method.apply(this._context, args);
};
```

Usage:

```
var methodsWorker = new MethodsWorker ();
methodsWorker.setContext(Math);
methodsWorker.defineMethod('sqrtOfSum', function() {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0, n = arguments.length; i < n; i++) {
        sum += arguments[i];
    }
    return this.sqrt(sum);
});
var result = methodsWorker.invoke('sqrtOfSum', [1, 2, 3]);
alert (result);
```